# Accessing multiple tables in SQLEXEC statement, SQL Pass Through

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I create a cursor called 'table1_data' from the statement:

`lnResult1 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, 'select * from table1 where status like ?m.seeStatus','table1_data')`

Now I want to access this table in my next SQLEXEC statement:

`lnResult2 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, 'select * from table2 where table2.item_id = table1_data.item_id','table2_data')`

however I get the error: The multi-part identifier table1_data.item_id could not be bound. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case table1_data is a local cursor and you cannot use it in second call which is made to server.
However since table1_data is also coming from server side you could instead do this:

```
*** Using text ... endtext just to make the SQL more readable

local lcSQL 
text to m.lcSQL noshow
select * from table2
where exists (select * from table1
              where table2.item_id = table1_data.item_id and 
                    table1.status like ?m.seeStatus);
endtext

lnResult1 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, 'select * from table1 where status like ?m.seeStatus','table1_data')
lnResult2 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, m.lcSQL,'table2_data')
```

EDIT: BTW you can return 2 results from a single SQLExec() call however  it is not worth it here in this case. Two separate queries as above is just fine (and remember you could make them updatable per table).

Comment: Thanks Cetin. I ended up doing something exactly like this yesterday so your message here is great confirmation! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables, but instead of SELECT * you should always neme the columns that you only need.

that helps also in future.

```
lnResult1_2 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, 'select table1.*,table2.* from table1, table2 where table2.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND  status like ?m.seeStatus')
```

I can't find any code related to joins, but

```
lnResult1_2 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, 'select table1.*,table2.* from table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.item_id = table1_data.item_id WHERE  status like ?m.seeStatus')
```

should also work, but as i said i can't find any code that uses explicit join, so you can give it a try and give a short response

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the first statement you posted should work, however I get an error because I am trying to create 2 cursors from this one statement. A cursor called 'table1_data', and a cursor called 'table2_data': lnResult1 = SQLEXEC(m.hConn, 'select table1.*, table2.* from table1,table2 where table2.item_id = table1.item_id and status like ?m.seeStatus','table1_data','table2_data'). Do you know how I would accomplish this creating 2 different cursors from this one SQLEXEC statement? I do not wish to join the tables so hopefully this method will work!

Comment: However, now that I think about it, I might need to accomplish this with two separate SQLEXEC statements anyways. Because the first one is creating table1_data, which I then use to create table2_data in the next SQLEXEC statement. Do you think my original question is possible, being able to access an already created cursor in a new SQLEXEC statement?

Comment: No, you can't use the cursor returned from SQLEXEC() in another query you're sending to the server because it's a VFP cursor. It doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to create 2 cursors with one SQLEXEC() statement? Otherwise Im not sure how I would accomplish my original goal..

Comment: the neew result table ahs all the data, you need only to pick the result set adntake what ever you need

Comment: @DizzleBeans, joining wouldn't have the same result and would create problems on updating back (remember SQL server doesn't allow multiple table updates).